# Application of Fermi-Walker derivative to specific problem

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

I am now reading about the tetrad formalism in GR and I am starting (how not) with the Wikipedia Article:

[Frame fields in general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_fields_in_general_relativity).

In this article, as an example, they show how tetrads can reexpress the Schwarzschild metric and how one can check if the observers are inertial non-spining frames using the Fermi derivative.

[image: Fermi derivative of the tetrads]

Can anyone extend the demostration for seeing how is applied this derivative to this vector fields? I would appreciate it.